# Jar not visible, but javaw.exe is running

Tags: java, swing, jar

On one of my Windows systems, I have a problem running a Jar file.

When I double click on my jar file, the first jFrame (splash screen) appears and hides again,but the main jFrame doesn't become visible ... When monitoring my services, I noticed that the javaw.exe keeps running ...

When launching the Jar from the command prompt (java -jar c:\myJar.jar), everything works fine ...

I've tried creating an output file while running the jar, and the file is created, but remains empty (java -jar c:\myJar.jar > d:\output.txt)

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java application will close (javaw.exe will close) after all of its threads finishes their work. So you are probably just disposing thread which was used to produce `JFrame`, but some other threads are still running (and probably waiting for something).

I can not help you further without more inforamtion about your specific application (e.g. your code)

Comment: Could this also be Windows-related issue, because I only have this problem on 1 of 5 computers ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the Java process using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) (which is in your JDK bin directory) and see what the threads are doing.

Have you tried running the app from the command line, but using javaw instead? javaw doesn't have access to a console, and it uses a different Win32 subsystem (WINDOWS vs. CONSOLE).

Comment: When using javaw.exe -jar from the command line. I have the same problem. When using java.exe -jar, it works fine ...

Comment: Find out what the threads are doing, though @Zereges answer is probably on the money.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The computer having the issue, was running Dexpot (Multiple desktop software)... It seems one of the desktops was corrupt, causing the problem.

Special thanks to aioobe, jdv and Zereges for all the help ...